# How to bind a specific port on a webclient object in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I am working on P2P application, I want to use the hole punching technique to connect peers.
here is my PHP third party Server Script.

```
<?php
echo "{yourIP:'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',yourPort:".$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']."}";
?>
```

In my C# code I created a server socket which listens to 8765, when i want to get my public IP address and port number (in order to share with the peers), I send a request to php server using WebClient Object. The problem is the webclient object uses random local port to make request.
How to bind a webclient object to 8765 port? so that always the requests use this port as source port.
thanks!

Sorry for my poor english!  :)

Comment: Probably a duplicate, look for http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788019/62662

Comment: I am not using socket, but webclient object how to bind webclient object?  using socket requires some concept of http protocol to be impelemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve this with WebClient, you can however solve it using HttpWebRequest:

```
public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BindIPEndpoint called");
      return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,5000);

}

public static void Main()
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://MyServer");

    request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

}
```